# iPhone - setStroke on an CGDrawArc using custom color not working

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics

I'm drawing a full circle using arcs in Core Graphics. Each arc of the circle is a different colour. If I use standard colours (e.g. `[UIColor redColor]` ) it draws fine. But if I specify a custom colour (e.g. a custom red colour `[UIColor colorWithRed:193 green:69 blue:57 alpha:1]` ) the colour is lost and it comes out white?!

Screen shot below, I've also code there for a slight shadow and semi-transparent circle.

[image: result using custom colour]

My code is below, its contained within the DrawRect method of my custom view. Any ideas on how I can use custom colours for the stroke of each arc?

```
for (DoughnutChartSliceObject *slice in _slices) {

    CGContextAddArc(ctx, self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2, _radius, slice.startAngleInRadians, slice.endAngleInRadians, 0);
    [slice.colour setStroke];

    //Define line width and cap
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, _stroke);
    CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapButt);

    //draw it!
    CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathStroke);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The components of the `UIColor` are from 0.0 to 1.0. Thus, I think you want:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:193.0/255.0 green:69.0/255.0 blue:57.0/255.0 alpha:1]
```

Comment: As an aside, while the redefining the color as laid out above should fix it, I personally would be inclined to use `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor` (passing it a `CGColorRef` such as `[slice.colour CGColor]`) in conjunction with `CGContextDrawPath`. I use `setStroke` when I'm then doing a `[myBezierPath stroke]`, but I use `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor` when I use `CGContextDrawPath`. Perhaps it doesn't matter (or at least when you're not using a custom context), but it seems a little more internally consistent.